# Option Menu show incorrectly on Custom Style map

Tags: java, android, styles, android-manifest

Option Menu show incorrectly on Custom Style map

The problem raised on an application in android

I have a custom theme on my app. The problem is that the option menu shows incorrectly ,so the option menu  shows cut of on the screen.

I wondering why could happen?

[image]

This is my style file xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

    <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>


</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>   
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_example</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any ones that have this same trouble, the solution , in my case , was solved by added this line in the manifest file.

```
<supports-screens
     android:anyDensity="true" />
```